# How to compare a column of a pandas dataframe to a list and move the matches to a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe's schema:

```
Unnamed Account_name   Date   Transaction_type Transaction_number     Name 
           Sales     04/14/21      Invoice          123456        Account name
```

The goal is to get a subset of the initial dataframe where the rows are only ones where the Name column matches a value in the list. I have a dataframe that fits this schema and am trying to match values using
`output_sheet = main_sheet[main_sheet['Name'].isin(verification_list)]`. Each time the output dataframe is empty. I have manually checked and seen that there are rows where the values match and am not sure how to fix this statement so that it properly extracts rows.

Comment: Are they exact matches, or is it perhaps matching `'Account name'` against `'Account Name'` and failing? Whitespace at the beginning, whitespace at the end, and capitalization can all matter.

Comment: So I found out the values I grabbed were converted from excel column to a list that contained a list that contained the value since I used .values.tolist(). Changing to list(verification_page.values.flatten()) seems to have worked. My bad on that.